# Github - Publishing website from docs folder - can I use resources (e.g. images) from root level?

Tags: github, github-pages

I was expecting this to work but it doesn't. Is it possible?

in my repo/docs folder I have a README.md file that contains

image.png exists in the repo root. I thought this would work and show the image on the webpage but it isn't working, no image is displayed.

Is it possible to reference files outside of the docs folder? If not, how would I go about doing this? The images I want to show are generated by the code and automatically created in the root. I guess I could create them in docs/images/ instead but they're not primarily being produced for the webpage, I just thought being able to show them would be an additional benefit.

Comment: When you say _show the image on the webpage_; are you referring to README.md rendering by GitHub?

Comment: Yep. It could equally be a index.html page though. The image shows on the READEME.md preview GitHub fine, it doesn't show on GitHub Pages though. I assume that's because GitHub Pages sets the docs/ folder as the web root and so anything above it can't be accessed.

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path to images? It should work fine with absolute paths; probably have issues with relative paths depending on domain naming and what not. Also `.md` files are converted to HTML by the GitHub and I don't believe browsers can natively process them.

Comment: Absolute paths don't work (and I wouldn't expect them to as it's outside of the web root) but I thought relative paths might still work (because the md -< html conversion happens server-side).